# Angled, wrapping CSS ribbon over image

Tags: css, ribbon

It is possible to achieve this ribbon using only CSS?

[image: Example image of ribbon I'm trying to create in CSS]

Comment: Have you tried anything...why not position and image?

Comment: if you leave off the little wrap-around edges, it's quite simple. Though IE8 and below would not support it.

Comment: As Rchristiani said, `1` a transparent PNG that's absolutely positioned can easily do the trick.  It will require pixel precision and won't be "flexible" but work well cross-browser.  `2` CSS3 transforms might have something that could be more flexible but lose more cross-browser capacity.  You could also prob. do a `3`"sliding door" like technique to with multiple images to have something more flexible. #1 would be the easiest to implement.

Comment: Thanks, I know this can be archived with an image :). Question is: is this design achievable using only CSS. @Jason I'd be interested in your solution since I can't seem to trim off the trailing ends of the overlay correctly.

Comment: I'm working on a JSFiddle for you. I've done this before, so I know it's possible.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```css
.box {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #a0a0a0;
    position: relative;
}
.ribbon {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg); 
     -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg); 
      -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg); 
       -o-transform: rotate(-45deg); 
          transform: rotate(-45deg); 
    border: 25px solid transparent;
    border-top: 25px solid #757575;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px;
    right: -50px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    width: 120px;
    color: white;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    size: 11px;
}
.ribbon .txt {
    position: absolute;
    top: -20px;
    left: 20px;
}​
```

```html
<div class="box">
    <div class="ribbon">
        <div class="txt">
            Example Text
        </div>
    </div>
<div>​
```

Comment: Fantastic, thank you! Only thing missing is the wrapping around the edges, I might be able to get around that with @mprquinn's solution.

Comment: The fiddle link doesn't work any more.  Is it still out there?

Comment: Yeah, sorry @Jaromjj, I moved it to Codepen: http://codepen.io/gilluminate/pen/jusoI